# ASP.NET Web api fileupload and IIS

Tags: asp.net-web-api

This is my code for uploading of files. When I run this on the `dev` server everything works just fine. But when I publish my app to IIS it stops working. The `fileInfo` class acts like the file doesn't exist.

`fileInfo.Length` throws an error also `fileInfo.Exists` is false.

And  `provider.FormData.Get("Note");` is returning null.

```
var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider("~/files");

Task<HttpResponseMessage> task =  Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider).ContinueWith(t =>
{
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(provider.FileData[0].LocalFileName);
float size = Convert.ToSingle(fileInfo.Length);
string note = provider.FormData.Get("Note");

..
..
..                                     
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the file folder did not have write permission.